# How to assign one Action Listener to a couple of buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                exite.setEnabled(true);
            }

        });

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                exite.setEnabled(true);
            }

        });


button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                exite.setEnabled(true);
            }

        });
```

I have 3 buttons here, but they are doing same thing. It takes some space in code. How can I group them all and assigned to one ActionListener?

Something like this. I don't know how it should be.

```
button1.button2.button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                exite.setEnabled(true);
            }

        });
```

Comment: create a class that extends ActionListener ( or implements.. ) then assign an instance of that class..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just assign the `ActionListener` to a different variable first:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    ...
};
button1.addActionListener(listener);
button2.addActionListener(listener);
button3.addActionListener(listener);
```

It's just a reference after all - the only "special" thing here is the use of an anonymous inner class to create an instance of `ActionListener`.

If there are multiple things that you want to do with all your buttons, you may well want to put them into a collection rather than having three separate variables for them, too.

Answer (score 2):

Juste create a variable :-)

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        exite.setEnabled(true);
    }
};
button1.addActionListener(listener);
button2.addActionListener(listener);
button3.addActionListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            exite.setEnabled(true);
        }

    };

button1.addActionListener(listener);
button2.addActionListener(listener);
button3.addActionListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement ActionListener in your class

```
public class YourClass implements ActionListener
```

That should make you have to implement an `actionPerformed` method in just one place where it can handle all your actions.
Your `addActionListener` lines should then become:

```
button1.addActionListener(this);
button2.addActionListener(this);
```

etc.

Then use:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource() == button1 || event.getSource() == button2 || event.getSource() == button3) {
        exite.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called event that implements the ActionListener for JButtons. Then use the parameter getCommand() method to get the text of the JButton and create if statements for all of the buttons based on the text that the JButton has, the code would be:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*
public class MultipleJButtons extends JFrame {
    JButton button1, button2, button3;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MultipleJButtons gui = new MultipleJButtons();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("Multiple Buttons");
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
    public MultipleJButtons() {
        event e = new event();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(e);

        button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(e);

        button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        add(button3);
        button3.addActionListener(e);
    }
    public class event implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            if (command.equals("Button 1")) {
                System.out.println("You pressed button 1");
            } else if (command.equals("Button 2")) {
                System.out.println("You pressed button 2");
            } else if (command.equals("Button 3")) {
                System.out.println("You pressed button 3");
            }
    }
```